# What is the role of -s flag in creating user

Tags: postgresql, rails-postgresql

I am trying to a create a user in postgres, I did the following.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser mystore
```

But I found out that I should use **-s flag** while creating the user, So my question is *what is role of -s flag while creating user.*

And I tried to remove the user by the following steps

```
sudo -u postgres psql 

drop user mystore
```

Then tried to create the store with the -s flag, it says 
role "mystore" already exists.

How to handle this

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it helped me. But should I delete the question?

Comment: Glad to hear it. I wasn't sure if it would solve your problem, but now that I know, I've made it an answer.

Comment: I thought like my question is too trivial, so you made a comment

Comment: If you run `createuser --help` it will tell you, another option is to read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html

Comment: Thanks man, that is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createuser -s` will give the new user superuser privileges. As with most command-line tools in Linux, you can get a description of each flag by running `createuser --help`.

The problem in `psql` appears to be a missing semicolon after your `drop` command. `psql` supports multi-line statements, so hitting Enter will simply add a new line; it won't submit the command to the server until it sees a semicolon terminator.